# How to read the math equation in English?

Tags: optimization, education

I want to know how to read mathematical formulas? For example：

- Q1: $$
   p^\text{new}=\mathop{\arg\max}_{p_j\in P^-}\{r_j\::\:|p_j-p_i|-r_i-r_j\geq 0, \forall p_i\in P^+\}$$
  A1:   the value p-new is defined of the output of the function arguments of the maxima applied to the set of value in parentheses (How to read the set of value in parentheses out professionally? ).
- Q2: $$\mathbf{PD}(P^+\bigcup Q)$$
  A2:
- Q3: $$P^+\setminus\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}.$$
  A3:
- Q4: $$|p^\text{new}-p_i|-r^\text{new}-r_i\geq 0,i=1,2,3,$$
  A4:
- Q5: $$  W_{ij}=\frac{\vert p_i-p_j \vert +\mu\vert r_i-r_j \vert}{\min(r_i,r_j)}.$$
- A5:
- Q6: $$p_i^f$$
  A6:
- Q7: $$\mathcal{G}' \text{(the latex code is \mathcal{G}')}$$
  A7:
- Q8: $$p_j\in \widehat{P^-}$$
  A8:

How to read this?

Comment: the value p-new is defined of the output of the function [arguments of the maxima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) applied to the set of value in parentheses

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Wow! Thanks! I have several such kind of equations. If it is possible to help me out? I can pay for you.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can we add each other on FB or wtsapp?

Comment: Thnaks... but no money for help on this site :-)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Wow! You are so kind. Give me 5 min, let me update the question. I believe there are many beginners know how to write but do not know how to read it out.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Updated!  Even you do not earn money, we can make a friend if you would like :D

Comment: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jan.nekovar/co/en/en.pdf I also read this, but far not enough.

Comment: $P$ is not defined anywhere... Usually $P^+$ means the set of "positive" elements of $P$ and $P^-$ the set of negative ones. $P^+ \setminus \{ p_1,p_2,p_3 \}$ is the set of "positive" $P$-elements without the values in parentheses. See [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory))

Comment: Q4 is simple: is a set of three formulas, one for each value of $i$ while Q5 defines a value $W_{ij}$ for each pair $(i,j)$ computing the value of formula in the numerator and dividing it by the minimum value between $r_i$ and $r_j$ (that will differe for each pair $(i,j)$).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA hi~ I actually know the meaning of each equation. But what I do not know is how to "read them out". Since I will make a presentation to say these formula out :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112204/discussion-between-frank-and-mauro-allegranza).